# Add users dynamically to htaccess

Tags: php, apache

I want to create a page that will allow for adding users dynamically to the .htaccess

Using PHP does present a security risk. I've looked for a while on the web but have not found any answers.

So the questions are: Is this even possible and if so how?

Comment: you mean this? http://www.apacheweek.com/features/userauth, please be more explicit and what you have tried please post code examples

Comment: I have htaccess set up and working. I also have a login setup that stores user credentials in MySQL. What I need now is how to pass the apache in and pw from the php login to apache.

Comment: I can pass info via HTTP. However, this requires the UN and PW to be hardcoded in a PHP file. Seem strange since the PHP file can easily be hacked.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do user administration with .htaccess!**

This file is meant **NOT** to be written by a world visible web script for security reasons!

What do you mean by "*Using PHP does present a security risk.*"?

**There is no such thing as a secure environment in using user interfaces and services!**